# SSH into vritual machine breaks when the ip addres changes

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, virtualbox

I am using Oracle VM where I created box with CentOS 7 and for network I am using Bridged Adapter with Wireless connection so I can use internet on the machine and also connect to it from the pc by ssh.

Now, from my main pc I ssh into the virtual machine based on the dynamic enp0s3 ip address but every time (every 15 - 30 minutes) when my ip changes my ssh connection breaks down and I need to reconnect. Is there a way to get the same connection type but without ssh breaks.

Comment: Assign a fixed IP address?

Comment: @DavidPostill Not sure where or how?

Comment: @Dividedbyzero Configure the SSH client with a static IP, either via the client's network adapter settings in tt's OS, or via the VM configuration page prior to booting the client

Comment: `autossh` does reconnect a `ssh` session automatically when it disconnects. But the previous session will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your own wireless router so that you can set up a fixed wireless adapter for your host machine.  I do this with my own wireless router here.

Or, use an Ethernet connection for the host machine. That should work also.

Comment: How does the author do this?  Can you be more specific?  The author’s knowledge on this subject is clearly lacking.

Answer (score 0):

You can define two network cards on your virtual machine, one bridged (already set) and another NAT. Then, visit NAT *advanced settings*, *Port mapping* to add this NAT rule:

```
| name | protocol |  host IP  | host port | guest IP  | guest port |
| ssh  |    TCP   | 127.0.0.1 |   7777    | 127.0.0.1 |      22    |
```

This will create a TCP socket on your host, listening incoming connections from localhost on port tcp/7777 to forward them to guest ssh port. Your guest machine SSH is then accessible from your host computer whichever guest machine IP address:

```
ssh -p 7777 127.0.0.1
```